# Is the word "dorm" acceptable in a thesis?

Tags: word-choice, nouns, formality, writing-style

I'm writing a thesis about students living in dormitories and I would like to know if  a *dorm* is an acceptable expression for a dormitory?

I don't live in GB nor in USA and the thesis is neither about students from GB nor from USA, so I don't see any difference between *residence hall* and *dormitory*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As bib mentioned, *dorm* is an informal word. [Collins agrees](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/dorm).

However, a [very interesting Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+the+dorms%2Cin+the+dormitories&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) that shows the informal word is steadily making headway into published works.

Normally, I would caution against using such informal language in a thesis. However, if dormitory life is the central theme of your thesis, using the lengthier *dormitory* over and over again might decrease the readability of your work.

I would suggest deliberately introducing the shorter word early on in your work:

> The dormitories (or "dorms") are where...

After that, you should be able to use the word *dorms* elsewhere in the document.

Really, though, you ought to check with your advisor on this.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that something like Ngram exists. It sure is a valuable insight.

Comment: It's a cool tool. You can even adjust the axis to view [percentages](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+the+dorms%2F%28in+the+dorms+%2B+in+the+dormitories%29%2Cin+the+dormitories%2F%28in+the+dorms+%2B+in+the+dormitories%29&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=4&share=)

Answer (score 5):

In the US, *dorm* is an [acceptable](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/dormitory?q=dorm) short form of *dormitory*, but in most cases would be considered [informal](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/dorm).

While there is no specific difference between *residence halls* and *dormitories*, the former would be more likely used in referring to educational settings, and the latter is used in all contexts, including both school and business settings.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I marked J.R.'s answer as accepted because it brings an interesting insight into the problem.

Comment: @Andrew I agree!